# Tracking current input character length before sending

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible and if yes, how do I make my code get constant track of my input's character length AS I'M TYPING so that I make it do something once I reach a certain number of chars?

Comment: it depends on where you are typing. A solution that should work everywhere is to count the number of pressed keyboard button and stops when the space is press

Comment: I am typing in the terminal and I will try your advice. I was stumped for a while, trying to get the len() to constantly check but alas.

Comment: So, what have you tried? I guess you've tried `input()` and realised that python gives you no information about what is happening. Did you search for other libraries?

Comment: I did use input()

Comment: @NicoCaldo but can such code be more specific? Because I am pretty sure that when you say button press, this includes the delete and backspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like that should work

```
import keyboard
count = 0
number_of_letters = # this will be the max number of letter you want to be typed

while True:
  key_read = keyboard.read_key()
  if count == number_of_letters:
    #do something
  if key_read == "space":
    print(count)
    count = 0
  elif key_read == 'backspace':
    count -= 1
  elif key_read.isalpha() or key_read.isnumeric()():
    count += 1
  else:
    pass
```

Basically the script stays in execution in background and count the button pressed. It detects only letters and numbers so, take into consideration the fact that if you try to type something like *_+.* it won't count. The code also doesn't consider the push of key such as SHIFT or DEL

Comment: But does it detect a backspace? Say, it lowers the count. Or does it just delete letters without lowering it?

Comment: @SomeGuy that's another thing to implement. Fixed